# Parsing JSON data in Swift

Tags: ios, mysql, json, swift, parsing

I'm trying to create an IOS application that reads MYSQL data from a website and displays it to the user. Here is the file that parses the data:

```
import UIKit
protocol HomeModelDelegate{
func itemsDownloaded(bar_data:[DataModel])
}

class HomeModel: NSObject {
var delegate:HomeModelDelegate?
func getItems() {
    //Hit the web service Url
    let serviceUrl = "OMITTED"
    //Download the json data
    let url = URL(string: serviceUrl)
    if let url = url{
        //Create a URL Session
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        let task = session.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
            if error == nil {
                //Succeeded                 
                //Call the parse json function on the data
                self.parseJson(data!)
            }              
            else {
                //Error occured
            }                             
        })          
       // Start the task
        task.resume()
    }             
    //Notify the view controller and pass the data back
}
 //Parse it out into DataModel structs
func parseJson(_ data:Data){        
    var bardataarray = [DataModel]()        
        //parse the data into DataModel structs
    do{
   //parse the data into a json object
        let jsonArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [Any]
    //loop through each result in the json array
        for jsonResult in jsonArray {
            //Cast json result as a dictionary
            let jsonDict = jsonResult as! [String:String]
            //create new bar data and set its properties
            let bardata = DataModel(name: jsonDict["Bar Name"]!, cover: jsonDict["Bar Cover"]!, deals: jsonDict["Drink Deals"]!)
        //add it to the array
            bardataarray.append(bardata)           
        }
        //TODO Pass the location array back to delegate 
        delegate?.itemsDownloaded(bar_data: bardataarray)         
    }
    catch{
        print("There was an error")
    }         
}
                         //eof
}
```

Here is the DataModel file:

```
import Foundation

struct DataModel {    
var name = ""
var cover = ""
var deals = ""
}
```

Here is the view controller:

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, 
HomeModelDelegate, UITextViewDelegate {  
var bar_info = [DataModel]()   
var homeModel = HomeModel()

@IBOutlet weak var LionCoverView: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    homeModel.getItems()
    homeModel.delegate = self
    updateCover()
}

func updateCover(){
    let size = bar_info.count
    print(size)  
}

func itemsDownloaded(bar_data: [DataModel]) {
    //adding files to array that we can work with

    self.bar_info = bar_data

    print(bar_data[2].name)
}

}
```

In the view controller, I try to assign the array of DataModels to the array bar_info that I initialized in the beginning of the view controller in the function itemsdownloaded, but the values aren't being sent. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I placed a print statement in itemsdownloaded to the console to make sure that the values in bar_data exist and when I run it the program is producing the correct value from the website, so why are these variables not being assigned to the DataModel array at the beginning of the view controller?

Comment: Why so many empty lines? Please edit your question.

Comment: You are calling `delegate?.itemsDownloaded(bar_data: bardataarray)` before the download is complete.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson How do I fix this problem? I'm not sure how to call delegate after the download is complete.

Answer (score 0):

You could use DispatchQueue.main.asynch to handle UI updates, something like below where you move the call to the delegate out of the `parseJson` func

```
let task = session.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
    if error == nil {
        self.parseJson(data!)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            delegate?.itemsDownloaded(bar_data: bardataarray)     
        }
    }
}
```